# write(/proc/<pid>/ctl): The requested resource is busy

Tags: aix

My application front end and back end are on java and c respectively. The interface is via listener processes on C-side. If there is an error on the c-side, the corresponding listener process which is serving the user needs to go down.

But the listener has not been going down in one of the cases. I have wracked my brains but I cannot seem to be able to crack it.

When I trussed the listener service, this is what I noticed.

```
15269900:       57278597: 0.0002:        _getpid()              = 15269900
15269900:       57278597: 0.0009:        _esend(11, 0x090000000B3B6F72, 1, 1, 0x0000000000000000) = 1
15269900:       57278597: kwrite(11, "\0\v\0\0\f\0\0\001\002", 11) = 11
15269900:       57278597: kread(11, "\0\v\0\0\f\0\0\001\001\0".., 8208) = 22
15269900:       57278597: 1.0974:        kread(11, "\0\v\0\0\f\0\0\001\002\0".., 8208) (sleeping...)
15269900:       57278597: 4.5260:        kread(11, "\0\v\0\0\f\0\0\001\002\0".., 8208) (sleeping...)
```

And it just waits here.

The procstack on this pid shows the below

```
0x0000000000000000  ????????() + ??
procstack: write(/proc/15269900/ctl): The requested resource is busy.
```

I have done my research but I am still unable to figure this out. Can somebody help me why the process is getting hung here?

Comment: Your process is read()ing from some file descriptor (file/pipe/socket).  We'd need more information on what exactly your listening process is listening on.